# HTML/CSS - Positioning tag from the right side of container, and to the right of another tag

Tags: html, css, image

I have a web page that has a div container with 3 images. Image 1 fills up the height of the container on the left side. Image 2 is centered in the container, but to the right of Image 1. Image 3 is in the bottom right corner of the container. I would like Image 3 to always be to the right of Image 1. Is there a way to achieve this using html/css? Currently if I resize the window, Image 3 covers up (or is covered by) Image 1 (depending on the z-index).

Sample Illustration:

```
- - - - - - - - 
|   |         |
|   |         |
|   | - - |   |
|   | - - |   |
|   |   | - - |
|   |   | - - |
- - - - - - - -
```

Sample Code:

```
<div background="{some background}" style="width: 100%; height: 750px; position: relative; background: {some background};">
    <img src="{some image 1}" style="position: absolute; width: auto; height: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 1;">
    <img src="{some image 2}" style="position: absolute; width: 456px; height: auto; margin: auto; top: 0; left: 432px; bottom: 0; z-index: 2;">
    <img src="{some image 3}" style="position: absolute; width: 456px; height: auto; margin: auto; bottom: 25px; right: 25px; z-index: 2;">
</div>
```

Comment: Your image3 has a right:35px and position absolute this will pull the image to the right of the screen you need to assing it the same left margin as images 2 to have them aligned

Comment: Image3 cover up because Image1 width is auto and all image position is absolute.

Comment: @AwRak, I don't want Images 2 & 3 to be aligned. I want them to always be to the right of Image 1; their position in the container is correct.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with the page markup and images ? it would be helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to set min-width on the parent Div

```
<div background="{some background}" style="width: 100%; min-width: 912px; height: 750px; position: relative; background: {some background};">
    <img src="{some image 1}" style="position: absolute; width: 456px; height: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 1;">
    <img src="{some image 2}" style="position: absolute; width: 456px; height: auto; margin: auto; top: 0; left: 432px; bottom: 0; z-index: 2;">
    <img src="{some image 3}" style="position: absolute; width: 456px; height: auto; margin: auto; bottom: 25px; right: 25px; z-index: 1;">
</div>
```

Note that it will work best when you define img 1's width as well then set the min width to the two images added together.

Comment: How would this fix Image 3 to the corner? I see how this would fix Image 3 to the right of Image 1, but I would like it to be both

Comment: your abs position of img 3 is what locks it to the corner, setting the min width of the parent div will just keep it from overlapping, which if i read correctly is what you wanted to do? Current img 3 overlaps img 1 because the width of the parent div drops below the combined width of both and the image has to go somewhere, since you use abs positioning you are pulling the images away from the flow control and thus they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 'position' to 'Fixed'

Comment: Fixed ties the image to the window, not the div container